# Pixel Activated Multiple Times for Facebook Pixel Tracking

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, tracking, facebook-pixel

I am using some Javascript I got from Facebook to execute a "tracking" pixel. But when I use the "Facebook Pixel Helper" to see if things are working correctly, it indicates there is an error, and the pixel is being activated multiple times. It gives no instructions on how to resolve such an error, or even where to look. Are there changes I can make in this code from Facebook that would prevent this multiple firing?

```
 <script>
    (function() {
        var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
        if (!_fbq.loaded) {
            var fbds = document.createElement('script');
            fbds.async = true;
            fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
            _fbq.loaded = true;
        }
        _fbq.push(['addPixelId', '368842449990820']);
    })();

    window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
    window._fbq.push(['track', 'PixelInitialized', {}]);
</script>
<noscript>
    <img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=368842449990820&amp;ev=PixelInitialized" />
</noscript>
```

Comment: Can you post the url where this is happening? Or set up a test page that replicates the behaviour that you can share?

Comment: by any chance do you have an iframe? we have the same problem and it comes from a second frame that initializes the pixel too. I didn't find any documentation that tells me if I need to initialize it in the child frame too.

Comment: Check in view source there must be two pixel ids

Comment: Same issue. Only one pixel id.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the "Facebook Pixel Helper" extension that sometimes led to this error.  They updated it today so you may be able to fix the error simply by updating to the latest version of the extension.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fb-pixel-helper/fdgfkebogiimcoedlicjlajpkdmockpc